# Why is CompareTo on short implemented this way?

Tags: .net, compareto, design-decisions

Consider the following code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(100.CompareTo(200)); // prints -1
            Console.WriteLine(((decimal)100).CompareTo((decimal)200)); // prints -1
            Console.WriteLine(((short)100).CompareTo((short)200)); // prints -100
            Console.WriteLine(((float)100).CompareTo((float)200)); // prints -1
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    } 
}
```

*My question is, are there any specific reasons the CompareTo-method on Int16 returns values other than -1, 0 and 1?*

ILSpy shows it is implemented this way

```
public int CompareTo(short value)
{
    return (int)(this - value);
}
```

whereas the method is implented on Int32 this way

```
public int CompareTo(int value)
{
    if (this < value)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (this > value)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The difference is that for `short`, there's no chance of the result overflowing. For instance, `short.MinValue - (short) 1` is still negative - whereas `int.MinValue - 1` is `int.MaxValue`.

In other words, the specific reason is that you can get away with a shortcut with `short` (no pun intended) whereas the same shortcut doesn't work with `int`. You should definitely not *require* [`IComparable<T>.CompareTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43hc6wht.aspx) implementations to return -1, 0 or 1. The documentation is pretty clear that the result is only meaningful in terms of being negative, zero, or positive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Didn't thought about the overflow issue. Unfortunately, I have to maintain a legacy application which contains a lot of code assuming CompareTo returns always -1, 0 or 1...

Comment: @dkson: I suggest you fix the legacy code. That sort of assumption will simply keep biting you until you eventually fix it. Better to do it sooner rather than later - and educate the original developers, if they're still around...

Answer (score 5):

Well, you should only really check the sign *anyway*, but for reasons: I guess for `int` etc there would be a risk of overflow/wrap (when handling 2 large-magnitude numbers) that would reverse the sign, meaning it *must* check the operators.

I'd rather it was consistent, but it doesn't seem to be a problem. More likely an optimisation that is atypical but within the documented API. In particular, optimising `short` here doesn't feel like it is going to get a *massive* amount of use (I *use* `short`, but not anything *like* as much as I do `int`).